# create a list of a dictionary that meets the condition of the dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, api, dictionary

hi I am new to python and I am trying to filter this dictionary with its values containing an empty list or a null value. below is the dictionary called response:

```
response = {'name': 'py', 
'title': 'Py', 
'description': 'Python library and collection of scripts that automate work on MediaWiki sites', 'url': 'https://www.me', 
'keywords': [], 
'author': [{'name': 'team'}], 
'repository': 'https://gecore', 
'subtitle': None, 
'id': None, 
'alternates': [], 
'username': None, 
'deprecated': False, 
'by': None, 
'experimental': False, 
'for': ['*'], 
'icon': 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pywikibot_MW_gear_icon.svg', 
'license': 'MIT', 
'sponsor': [], 
'available_languages': [], 
'technology_used': ['python'], 
'tool_type': 'framework', 
'api': None, 
'developer_url': [{'d_url': 'https://www.mement', 'language': 'en'}], 
'user_url': [{'language': 'en', 'm_url': 'https://www.Spec'}, {'t_url': 'https://doc.media', 'language': 'en'}], 
'feedback': [], 
'privacy': [], 
'translate_url': 'https://translate.bot', 
'bugtracker_url': 'https://phabbot/', 
'annotations': {
'wid': None, 
'depre': False, 
'by': None, 
'exp': False, 
'for': [], 
'icon': None, 
'available_languages': ['en'], 
'ttype': None, 
'rey': Null, 
'api': None, 
'dev_doc': [{'url': 'https://www.medial:t', 'language': 'en'}], 'user_url': [], 
'feedback': [], 
'privacy': [], 
'translat': None, 
'bugtracker': None}, 
'_schema': None, 
'_language': 'en', 
'origin': 'api', 
'created_by': {'id': 10, 'username': 'JJMC89'}, 
'created_date': '2021-10-12T20:26:29.012245Z', 
'modified_by': {
'id': 3, 
'username': 'BD'
}, 
'modified_date': Null}
```

my code:

```
print([response if response.values() == [] or Null or None])
```

i got an error while running this on jupyter notebook. my code is trying to filter the dictionary with the condition( where the values of the dictionary has an empty list or a null value) - to create a list of dictionary that meets this condition.

Comment: how you are storing `NULL` or this is a variable in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null does not exists. You can use `np.nan` from `numpy`.

```
response = {'name': 'py', 
    'title': 'Py', 
    'description': 'Python library and collection of scripts that automate work on MediaWiki sites', 'url': 'https://www.me', 
    'keywords': [], 
    'author': [{'name': 'team'}], 
    'repository': 'https://gecore', 
    'subtitle': None, 
    'id': None, 
    'alternates': [], 
    'username': None, 
    'deprecated': False, 
    'by': None, 
    'experimental': False, 
    'for': ['*'], 
    'icon': 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pywikibot_MW_gear_icon.svg', 
    'license': 'MIT', 
    'sponsor': [], 
    'available_languages': [], 
    'technology_used': ['python'], 
    'tool_type': 'framework', 
    'api': None, 
    'developer_url': [{'d_url': 'https://www.mement', 'language': 'en'}], 
    'user_url': [{'language': 'en', 'm_url': 'https://www.Spec'}, {'t_url': 'https://doc.media', 'language': 'en'}], 
    'feedback': [], 
    'privacy': [], 
    'translate_url': 'https://translate.bot', 
    'bugtracker_url': 'https://phabbot/', 
    'annotations': {
    'wid': None, 
    'depre': False, 
    'by': None, 
    'exp': False, 
    'for': [], 
    'icon': None, 
    'available_languages': ['en'], 
    'ttype': None, 
    'rey': np.nan, 
    'api': None, 
    'dev_doc': [{'url': 'https://www.medial:t', 'language': 'en'}], 'user_url': [], 
    'feedback': [], 
    'privacy': [], 
    'translat': None, 
    'bugtracker': None}, 
    '_schema': None, 
    '_language': 'en', 
    'origin': 'api', 
    'created_by': {'id': 10, 'username': 'JJMC89'}, 
    'created_date': '2021-10-12T20:26:29.012245Z', 
    'modified_by': {
    'id': 3, 
    'username': 'BD'
    }, 
    'modified_date': np.nan}
```

You must return the name of the key, because the value is uninformed.
You can do with (searching also for nested dict):

```
nulls = []
    for key in response:
        if isinstance(response[key], dict):
            nested_dict = response[key]
            for key_ in nested_dict:
                if nested_dict[key_] in [np.nan, [], None]:
                    nulls.append(key_)
            
        elif response[key] in [np.nan, [], None]:
            nulls.append(key)
    
      Output:
     ['keywords',
     'subtitle',
     'id',
     'alternates',
     'username',
     'by',
     'sponsor',
     'available_languages',
     'api',
     'feedback',
     'privacy',
     'wid',
     'by',
     'for',
     'icon',
     'ttype',
     'rey',
     'api',
     'user_url',
     'feedback',
     'privacy',
     'translat',
     'bugtracker',
     '_schema',
     'modified_date']
```

Comment: thank you for your response. however, the expected output should also take into consideration the nested dictionary called annotations

Comment: @BrieTasi I modified my answer for dealing with nested dict

Answer (score 1):

The error here is that you only compare the response to the empty list `[]` but not to `None`. Basically what you are doing is asking if the value is an empty list or if None, but only that. What you want to do is separate the condition, such as

```py
print([r for r in response.values() if not r or r is None])
```

The `not r` catches both an empty list and the boolean `False`.

Alternatively you can use the `filter` function

```py
list(filter(lambda x: not x, response.values()))
```

But that will give you only the values. If you want the keys, you might want to do:

```py
print([k for k,v in response.items() if not v])
```

That will output

```py
['keywords', 'subtitle', 'id', 'alternates', 'username', 'deprecated', 'by', 'experimental', 'sponsor', 'available_languages', 'api', 'feedback', 'privacy', '_schema', 'modified_date']
```

If you want to also support the nested dicts, a single line might not be enough, but recursion might do it.

```py
def get_nones(resp, result):
...     for k, v in resp.items():
...             if not v:
...                     result.append(k)
...             elif isinstance(v, dict):
...                     get_nones(v, result)
...     return result
... 
>>> r = []
>>> get_nones(response, r)
['keywords', 'subtitle', 'id', 'alternates', 'username', 'deprecated', 'by', 'experimental', 'sponsor', 'available_languages', 'api', 'feedback', 'privacy', 'wid', 'depre', 'by', 'exp', 'for', 'icon', 'ttype', 'rey', 'api', 'user_url', 'feedback', 'privacy', 'translat', 'bugtracker', '_schema', 'modified_date']
```

> by the way, this works because Python passes its lists by reference and not by value. The last line of the function `return result` is just to have it at the end, but there is no need to update the value during recursion as it is the same object that is being passed.

Hope it helps

Comment: the parameter 'result' was not defined

Comment: What do you mean, where is it not defined?

Answer (score 0):

Null is not a Keyword in python.

So, you will have to convert it to None or "Null"

```
print([resp for resp in response.values() if resp == [] or resp == "Null" or resp == None])
```

Comment: thank you for your response. however, this does not print the keys alongside the values and it does not account for the nested dictionary(annotations)